# Angular / Ionic with Angularfire: iOS: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8100"

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic3, angularfire2, angularfire

This Ionic3 (Angular 5) project had to be upgrade from an old AngularFire 3.x to  "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1";
Since that ugprade, a strange behavior happens when running the app in Chrome using the "device mode" set to iPhone/iPad. Doesn't occur on Android simulation. At some point (which I can't identify), angularfire (I guess?) seems to add an iframe in the body element:

```
<iframe ng-non-bindable="" frameborder="0" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" tabindex="0" vspace="0" width="100%" 
    id="I0_1562593422051"
    name="I0_1562593422051" 
    src="https://XXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/iframe?apiKey=YYYYYYYYYYYYYY&amp;appName=ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ&amp;v=6.2.4&amp;usegapi=1&amp;jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en_GB.4xsMIUspm18.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCO_dMVTlnY55ZJNnloXSQJ2GsU_yw%2Fm%3D__features__#id=I0_1562593422051&amp;_gfid=I0_1562593422051&amp;parent=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100&amp;pfname=&amp;rpctoken=33463188" style="position: absolute; top: -100px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"></iframe>
```

Even though this works perfectly on the firebaseapp.com subdomain, the localhost (which is used in cordova) encounters the following problem with iOS only (not with android, not with chrome)...

Any advice welcome, this is the 2nd day spent troubleshooting..! Thanks in advance.

Some obscure stack suggests an error at core.js:1449:

```
core.js:1449 ERROR DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8100" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at e (<anonymous>:1:62513)
    at e (<anonymous>:1:63249)
    at e (<anonymous>:1:63249)
    at e (<anonymous>:1:63249)
    at e (<anonymous>:1:63249)
    at e (<anonymous>:1:63249)
    at e (<anonymous>:1:63249)
    at e (<anonymous>:1:63249)
    at e (<anonymous>:1:63249)
    at e (<anonymous>:1:63075)
defaultErrorLogger  @   core.js:1449
ErrorHandler.handleError    @   core.js:1510
IonicErrorHandler.handleError   @   ionic-error-handler.js:61
next    @   core.js:5508
schedulerFn @   core.js:4342
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @   Subscriber.js:253
SafeSubscriber.next @   Subscriber.js:191
Subscriber._next    @   Subscriber.js:129
Subscriber.next @   Subscriber.js:93
Subject.next    @   Subject.js:53
EventEmitter.emit   @   core.js:4322
(anonymous) @   core.js:4782
t.invoke    @   polyfills.js:3
r.run   @   polyfills.js:3
NgZone.runOutsideAngular    @   core.js:4708
onHandleError   @   core.js:4782
t.handleError   @   polyfills.js:3
r.runTask   @   polyfills.js:3
e.invokeTask    @   polyfills.js:3
i.isUsingGlobalCallback.invoke  @   polyfills.js:3
n   @   polyfills.js:3
setTimeout (async)      
o   @   polyfills.js:3
t.scheduleTask  @   polyfills.js:3
onScheduleTask  @   polyfills.js:3
t.scheduleTask  @   polyfills.js:3
r.scheduleTask  @   polyfills.js:3
r.scheduleMacroTask @   polyfills.js:3
(anonymous) @   polyfills.js:3
o.<computed>    @   polyfills.js:2
hostReportError @   hostReportError.js:8
setTimeout (async)      
o   @   polyfills.js:3
t.scheduleTask  @   polyfills.js:3
r.scheduleTask  @   polyfills.js:3
r.scheduleMacroTask @   polyfills.js:3
(anonymous) @   polyfills.js:3
o.<computed>    @   polyfills.js:2
AsyncObserver.scheduleEvent @   index.cjs.js:18817
AsyncObserver.next  @   index.cjs.js:18806
QueryListener.raiseInitialEvent @   index.cjs.js:16065
QueryListener.onViewSnapshot    @   index.cjs.js:16007
EventManager.onWatchChange  @   index.cjs.js:15944
(anonymous) @   index.cjs.js:16653
step    @   tslib.es6.js:99
(anonymous) @   tslib.es6.js:80
fulfilled   @   tslib.es6.js:70
t.invoke    @   polyfills.js:3
r.run   @   polyfills.js:3
(anonymous) @   polyfills.js:3
t.invokeTask    @   polyfills.js:3
r.runTask   @   polyfills.js:3
o   @   polyfills.js:3
e.invokeTask    @   polyfills.js:3
p   @   polyfills.js:2
v   @   polyfills.js:2
```

My package.json dependencies:

```
   "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/cdk": "^5.1.0",
        "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^5.0.0-beta.15",
        "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
        "@ionic-native/core": "~4.11.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.11.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.11.0",
        "@ionic/pro": "^2.0.3",
        "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
        "@ngrx/effects": "^5.2.0",
        "@ngrx/store": "^5.2.0",
        "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^5.2.0",
        "@types/cordova": "0.0.34",
        "cordova-android": "^7.1.4",
        "cordova-browser": "^5.0.4",
        "cordova-ios": "^4.5.5",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic": "^5.3.1",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.5.1",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
        "firebase": "^6.2.4",
        "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
        "ionic2-auto-complete": "^1.6.2-alpha",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "ng2-nvd3": "^2.0.0",
        "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^5.3.5",
        "rxjs": "6.2.0",
        "rxjs-compat": "6.2.0",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.26"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

It is related to Chrome - desktop edition. Both W10 and Mac behave the same when in "device mode", simulating and iOS device. It happens when 1 or multiple .stateChange calls are performed when willing to monitor a server-side filtered collection. Occurs randomly - tested in a separate sandbox.
As suggested, this doesn't happen on the actual Safari of iOS. Even Chrome for iOS behave nicely, so this problem can be considered "linked to dev environment".